# Iterator and Increment operator

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to find in an array the first two adjacent neighbours and return an iterator to the first one. In the code below, writing "ForwardIterator next = ++first; " doesn't give the result I want, but it seems it's correct. On the other hand, writing "ForwardIterator next = first; ++next; " works fine. So, what am I missing?

```
template<class ForwardIterator>

ForwardIterator MyAdjacent(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
ForwardIterator next = ++first; 
while (first != last)
{
    if (*first == *next) break;
    else
        ++first;
        ++next;
}
return first;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that `next = ++first` mutates `first`? `*first == *next` should always be true in this code.

Comment: This happens to not be a problem for your code, but the fact that `++next` is indented under your `else` doesn't actually make it fall under your `else`.

Comment: Your indentation is very confusing. ++next; should be aligned with the if/else. Also I'd recommend being more consistent, e.g., put the 'break' on the line following the 'if' in the same way that '++first' is on the line following the else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForwardIterator next = ++first;` will modify `first`, so `next` will always be the equal to `first`. Instead, try:

```
ForwardIterator next = std::next(first);
```

This will give you the incremented iterator without modifying `first`. You will need to `#include <iterator>` at the top of your file. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next